# No audio with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Optiplex 7050, however, I had a problem in sound, I had no audio, even after typing some commands, the sound sign from the toolbar has been disappeared. So can anyone help me.. I think, I should install the driver (sound driver manually ).

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu 16.04 instead. It will have more bug fixes and better support from the community.

Comment: But I do not wanna upgrade that version, so can anyone help the solution for such problem

Comment: You can also install a newer kernel temporarily and see if that solves the problem.